# Calculating vinegar strength

Tags: acid-base

The pKa of vinegar is 4.76. If I know the  pH of the vinegar, what would be the formula for determining the percentage acid base on the relationship between pH, pKa and concentration? Can you show the formula so that I only need to plug in the ph?

I am not a chemistry student and I have not done these kinds of calculations. I am searching for a convenient way for farmers in developing countries to quickly approximate the strength of vinegar. The final test would be done in a lab but I need a way for them to test vinegar other than titration because titration can seem more like witchcraft than science to the uninitiated.

Comment: What is the definition of pKa? Ka is the equilibrium constant of which reaction? Try to write something. It is not difficult.

Comment: I understand that, "pKa = -log10Ka The lower the pKa value, the stronger the acid."

I am not a chemistry student and I have not done these kinds of calculations. I am searching for a convenient way for farmers in developing countries to quickly approximate the strength of vinegar. 

The final test would be done in a lab but I need a way for them to test vinegar other than titration because titration can seem more like witchcraft than science to the uninitiated :-).

Answer (score 2):

If $pK_a = 4.76$, then $K_a = 1.74 \times 10^{-5}$

Then approximating that $K_a$ can be written in terms of concentration rather than the true definition which is in terms of activities:

$K_a = 1.74 \times 10^{-5}M = \frac{[A-][H+]}{[HA]} = \frac{[H+]^2}{c-[H+]} $

$1.74 \times 10^{-5}M = \frac{[H+]^2}{c-[H+]} $

where $c$ is the molar concentration of the vinegar

If you want pH explicitly in the equation, then approximating pH = -log[H+], then:

$1.74 \times 10^{-5}M = \frac{(10^{-pH}M)^2}{c-(10^{-pH}M)} $

So, for example if pH is 3, $10^{-3}$ is 0.001, so

$1.74 \times 10^{-5} = \frac{10^{-6}M}{c-(10^{-3}M)}$

$1.74 \times 10^{-5}c -1.74 \times 10^{-8}M = 10^{-6}M$

$1.74 \times 10^{-5}c = 1.02 \times 10^{-6}M$

$c = 0.059M$

Comment: Thanks.

What does the H+, the HA and the M stand for? 

If the ph is 3, what would the math look like?

Comment: `pKa = -log(Ka)`, the Ka value calculated is not correct

Comment: http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemistryglossary/g/Pka-Definition.htm

What is it?

Comment: Hope this isn't double posting, but I am not understanding some of the symbols and I am not familiar with the conventions. 

What do the M, H+ and HA stand for? 

I am trying to come up with a formula where the only variable is the ph which the farmer would get with a ph meter, do the math and calculate the acidity of her vinegar. 

The Ka, according to the formula DavePhD gave, is .000174 because the pKa for vinegar is 4.76. The molar mass is 60.05196 g/mol. So assuming the ph is 3, could some write out the "long math" for this? Are other numbers needed to solve this?

Comment: I want to solve for concentration or percentage of acetic/ethanoic acid in the solution.

Comment: Concentration is c in the final formula.  The units are M which means moles per liter. In the final equation there is only c and pH, and since pH will be known, c is the only unknown.

Comment: How do I read the (10−pHM)2/c−(10−pHM)? Am I multiplying the ph by the moles per liter (60...), subtracting it from 10 and squaring that number. Then dividing that by the same (10−pHM)and the solving for c?

Comment: M is just there to make the units work out.  M is not a variable.  You raise 10 to the (-pH) power. So for pH 3, 10 to the -3 power is 0.001.

Comment: @VinegrMan I added an example with pH=3 to the end of the answer

Comment: I believe the definition for the acid dissociation constant already includes all approximations and is therefore correctly defined with concentrations.

Comment: @Martin I don't think there is an IUPAC definition, but for example in Levine's Physical Chemistry it is a(H3O+)a(X-)/a(HX)a(H2O).  Then Levine says a(H2O)=1 is an approximation, and considering only the activity coefficients of the charged species is a further approximation.

Comment: @Martin definition in terms of activity discussed here: http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1998/an/a705491b/unauth#!divAbstract

Comment: I think it is this lack of official definition, that may cause confusion here. I thought of it, as it is presented in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant#Equilibrium_constant). However, for the purpose of most calculations, the difference should be negligible. Thanks for the article, it was quite interesting to read.

Comment: I think for 5% acetic acid (typical vinegar) proper consideration of the decrease in water concentration from 55.5M to 52.8M and the activity coefficients of all the species would make a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

As we know:
$$\rm pH=\frac12(pKa-\log C)\quad\mid\quad C=\frac{\rm weight\;of\;acid}{\rm Mol\;wt.*Volume of sln.}\quad\mid\quad Strength=C*Mol.\;wt.$$
Calculating:
$$\rm S=10^{pKa-2pH}*M$$
So finally:
$$\huge\fbox{$\rm S=10^{4.75^{\#}-2pH}*60.05$}$$
<sub>#You can as well take that 4.76</sub>

Theoretically It is correct but some deviations are bound to occur in reality. I suggest finding out that in few samples first.